# I don't understand why my div with height auto is taking the full height of its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a div.grid that contains multiple `div.column` inside using flexbox. When a `div.column` increases in height due to having more content inside, all other `div.column` also increase in height.

It is to my understaind that this shouldn't help as their height is set to auto.

Also, my grid is using the flex display, with `flex-wrap: wrap`. I think is what is causing it, but I haven't found any explanation to why it is changing the children's height.

I have tried changing the following properties, in different combinations and manners, of parent and children: position, display, height.

These are the computed styles only, not my actual code.

```css
div.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 960px;
}

div.column {
    display: block;
    flex-basis: 37.5%;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    /* height is actually set to auto, but it is computed like this */
    height: 132px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="column">something</div>
    <div class="column">something<br>else<br>here</div>
    <div class="column">something</div>
</div>
```

I expected the children to not fill the full height of the parent when the children don't all have the same amount of content.

[image]

Comment: Provide a  [mcve]

Comment: @LGSon It's there

Comment: Flex row parent default `align-items` value (for wrapped items, `align-content`) is `stretch`, hence children will fill its (parent) height. Setting it to e.g. `flex-start` will make them top align.

Comment: Men, I am actually pissed it was this simple. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As LGSon has asnwered in the comments:

Using `flex: display` automatically defaults `align-items` to `stretch` making the height of the children stretch to fill the height of the wrapper. It is also not shown in the computed properties, which is why it didn't cross my mind to check it.

Therefore, the solution was to add `align-items: flex-start` to `.grid`.